# Spring boot 3.1 + Spring security 6.1 authorizeHttpRequests permitAll not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Basically every time I make a Spring boot micro-service I have to waste time trying to configure the app with the new API changes. 7 months ago they deprecated the `WebConfigurerAdapter` and i had to spend 4 days trying to make it work. Last week I started developing a new service and want to permit all routes (for now) but the config used in the official docs not working.

this is my `Config.java`

`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(session ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`

I haven't found any online code example with the new lamda style config and this isn't working.

This is my 7 months old working config :

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .cors()
            .disable();
    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            //.authenticated()
            .permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

I don't really get the problem here but it feels like the Bean is not being created at all. When I try to log something inside the method nothing works and the `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` not printing anything to the console.

Answer (score 2):

also had this problem, resolve it.
Working code:
Spring Boot: 3.1.5

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
}
```